# Cmake capturing undesired includes

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, cmake

After the upgrade of a mac os to mavericks, my project was not compiling anymore with the new compiler (a clang 5.1...).

So I installed an old gcc 4.2 following the explanation in this link.

https://coderwall.com/p/lqpp8w

Then I modified the symbolic links cc and c++ to point on that gcc I've just installed

When I run cmake, it does find now the compilers of gcc 4.2 instead of the clang 5.1. However it still wants to use the includes from the new xcode:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/
```

Instead of those of the compilers found:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/include/gcc/darwin/4.2/
```

Here is the output of my cmake

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.2.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.2.1
-- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot
-- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot - yes
-- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
-- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot - yes
-- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
-- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
```

and on CMakeCache.txt I have the following

```
CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/
```

How can I get rid of that bad includes?

Thanks.

Comment: `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang` and `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang` does not fit Your needs?

Comment: Sorry but I don't see the point. Why would I set those to clang if I want to use gcc?

Comment: oops, sorry, I meant `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang` and `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=gcc` accordingly.

Comment: @ruslo How do I check that?

Comment: @ruslo, yes I did but same result. And after some googling, I found out that it is normal that Apple-gcc uses those files and if I try to rename Xcode, it will complaning saying that it can t find xcode.

Comment: Still I am unable to compile my old project :/

Comment: @ruslo I don't set it anywhere. It is automatically set by CMAKE. I wish i could just disable this option.
Before the upgrade i didn t have those 4 lines:
-- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot
-- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot - yes
-- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
-- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes